# If $p \in H^m$ and $v \in T_p H^m$, then the geodesic $\gamma: R \rightarrow H^m$ is given by $\gamma(t) = \cosh(t)p + \sinh(t) v$

Tags: geodesy

Let $p \in H^{m}$ and $ v ∈ T_{p}H^{m} $ be given with $Q(v,v) = 1$. Then the geodesic $γ : R → H^{m}$ with $γ(0) = p $ and $˙γ^{'}(0) = v$ is given by $$γ(t) = \cosh(t)p + \sinh(t)v$$
with the Lorentz-Mikownsk metric. I have tried the definition in local coordinates but I have not been able to reach the result, if you have any advice I would appreciate it.

Comment: What is $H^m$?  Cheers!

Comment: Is the Hyperbolic space